# Looping in Python showing me some errors

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

[I am trying to write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NMQN.png)

Comment: Posting your code as an image link makes it harder for other to help you.  Please post your code as plain text, and explain what exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure why you would need a try-catch block... there’s no exception that exists to be catched anyways.

```
nums = []

while True:
  x = input(“Enter a number: “)
  if x == “done”:
    print(min(nums), max(nums))
    break
  elif x.isnumeric():
    nums.append(x)
  else:
    print (“Please enter a numeric input”)
```